# Override CurrentCulture for WinForms control

Tags: winforms, controls, currentculture, currentuiculture

Is it possible to override the `CurrentCulture` and the `CurrentUICulture` for a specific control in WinForms? So that this one specific control uses a different culture?

Comment: Reading your question again I realize that I may have misunderstood you... I first read it as if you are making a control that you want to have another culture, but now I realize that you perhaps want to have an existing control (like Button) act using a different culture...

Comment: last thing is correct. I have an existing control (without access to the source) and I would like that this control is using a different culture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by instantiating the CultureInfo of your choice and pass that as a parameter to formatting functions (such as ToString). Just don't assign it to Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture or Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, since that will change the culture for the application as such.

In your code:

```
CultureInfo myCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(myCulture));
```

If your code executes external code, and you want to force this code to use your internally chosen culture, you can do that by creating a new thread, assign the culture to that thread and then have that thread execute the code. Just make sure to pay attention to the threading issues that comes with that approach.

Thread sample:

```
string formattedDate = string.Empty;
Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
{
    // call external code without specifying culture
    formattedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();  
    waitHandle.Set();
});
t.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
t.Start();
waitHandle.WaitOne(); // wait for the thread to finish
Console.WriteLine(formattedDate);
```

As a last point; I don't know *why* you want to override the CurrentCulture, but I would suggest that you think twice before doing so. Users are used to seeing dates an numbers formatted according to their locale; changing that could be confusing, especially if it happens in just one part of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it for single control, but for the current thread you can switch like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("DE");
```

Comment: Hi, I know how to set it for the entire thread, but this doesn't help me, as I need to change it for a special control on my form.