# Need to have a ProgressBar (not Marqee style) move back and forth

Tags: winforms, progress-bar

I am using a ProgressBar which can be either of a Continuous or Blocks style (I cannot enable the visual styles in my application).

I made it work by advancing step by step

The code is like this one (looked on *msdn*):

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();
void progressbar1_visibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var progressb = sender as ProgressBar;
    if (progressb != null && progressb.Visible == true)
    {
        InitializeProgress();
    }
}    

private void InitializeProgress()
{
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    timer.Interval = 50;
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(IncreaseProgressBar);
    timer.Start();
}

private void IncreaseProgressBar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (progressBar1.Value >= progressBar1.Maximum)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;    
    }

    progressBar1.Increment(1);

 }
```

(and the progress bar is shown\hidden from different *workers* that perform different actions)

How ever, it looks ugly to me, I would like it move from left to right\right to left.

How can I achieve that ?

Many thanks

Comment: You should create a custom one, the standard progressbar is very limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  [Override CurrentCulture for WinForms control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925145/override-currentculture-for-winforms-control) to a right-to-left language (such as Hebrew - "he" or "he-IL") which is a bit tricky as this is possible only for Threads (and not e.g. for forms or controls).
Then set the progress bar control property "RightToLeft" to "Yes", and "RightToLeftLayout" property to "True".
Now your progress bar should go RTL. If it doesn't or changing to RTL culture hurts more than it gives, the only option I can see is creating a custom control for the job.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmmm, thanks, I just want to make sure you understood my question correctly: I need the ProgressBar to move back and forth, not just right to left.

Comment: For that you need to do the thing above and switch back to "LTR" when needed. Sadly, there's no other option for the built-in Progress Bar. It's either RTL or LTR which means one end is "locked" the other "moves" which is either left or right. No escape. If you want something dynamic, it is a must to create your own control (or download/buy one like telerik's if that fits your needs)

Comment: Thanks, I left the current implementation